# declaring enum in global scope

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.4 c89

I have the following in my state.c file:

```
enum State {
    IDLE_ST,
    START_ST,
    RUNNING_ST,
    STOPPED_ST,
};

State g_current_state = State.IDLE_ST;
```

I get the following error when I try and compile.

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘g_current_state’
```

Is there some with declaring a variable of type enum in global scope?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two ways to do this in straight C. Either use the full `enum` name everywhere:

```
enum State {
    IDLE_ST,
    START_ST,
    RUNNING_ST,
    STOPPED_ST,
};
enum State g_current_state = IDLE_ST;
```

or (this is my preference) `typedef` it:

```
typedef enum {
    IDLE_ST,
    START_ST,
    RUNNING_ST,
    STOPPED_ST,
} State;
State g_current_state = IDLE_ST;
```

I prefer the second one since it makes the type look like a first class one like `int`.

Answer (score 3):

`State` by itself is not a valid identifier in your snippet.

You need `enum State` or to typedef the `enum State` to another name.

```
enum State {
    IDLE_ST,
    START_ST,
    RUNNING_ST,
    STOPPED_ST,
};

/* State g_current_state = State.IDLE_ST; */
/* no State here either ---^^^^^^         */
enum State g_current_state = IDLE_ST;
```

/* or */

```
typedef enum State TypedefState;
TypedefState variable = IDLE_ST;
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing semicolon after the closing brace of the `enum`. By the way, I really do not understand why missing semicolon errors are so cryptic in gcc.

Comment: No, that wasn't the reason. I am still getting the error. thanks

Answer (score 2):

So there are 2 problems:

1. Missing `;` after `enum` definition.
2. When declaring the variable, use `enum State` instead of simply `State`.

This works:

```
enum State {
    IDLE_ST,
    START_ST,
    RUNNING_ST,
    STOPPED_ST,
};

enum State g_current_state;
```